# Dynamically load data with @Ajax.ActionLink using Skip() and Take()

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to `ASP.NET MVC`, so please help me to solve this, at a first glance, simple issue.

I have a table of students on my `View` and a `Load More` link below it. By clicking on this link I need to load more students records with AJAX.

So this is my `View` (omitted unnecessary data)

```html
<table id="studentTable">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @Html.Partial("_StudentDetailsList", Model)
    </tbody>
</table>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Load More", "LoadMoreStudents", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
    UpdateTargetId = "studentTable"
})
```

`_StudentDetailsList` partial view to display students

```html
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Student>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

action

```cs
public ActionResult LoadMoreStudents(int skip = 0)
{
    return PartialView("_StudentDetailsList", studentRepository.Get(orderBy: s => s.OrderBy(st => st.FirstName).OrderBy(st => st.LastName)).Skip(skip).Take(10));
}
```

So as you can see, I want to load next 10 students every time, but I have to know how much are already loaded. So the question is: from where should I get this `skip` parameter which I want to pass to the `Action` from the `View`. How can I count on the `View` how many partial views are already loaded and how many students each partial has? Or is it a bad practice to pass this parameter to action, maybe I should handle it somewhere else (e.g. some service)? Please advice the right way to do this. Thanks.

P.S. Please feel free to edit the caption as I can't come up with appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to create a ViewModel that contains these variables for you.

**ViewModel**

```
public class YourViewModel(){

    public int skip {get;set;}

    public IEnumerable<StudentDetails> StudentDetailList {get;set;}

}
```

**The Controller/Action Method**

```
public ActionResult LoadMoreStudents(int skip = 0)
{
    return PartialView("_StudentDetailsList", new YourViewModel{
      StudentDetailList = studentRepository.Get(orderBy: s => s.OrderBy(st => st.FirstName).OrderBy(st => st.LastName)).Skip(skip).Take(10),
      skip = skip + 10});
}
```

**The View**
            @Html.Partial("_StudentDetailsList", Model.StudentDetailList)

**The Partial View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.YourViewModel
<table id="studentTable">
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>    
  @foreach (var item in Model.StudentDetailList)
   {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Load More", "LoadMoreStudents", new {skip = Model.skip}, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
        UpdateTargetId = "studentTable"
    })
```

Basically, you have to be able to dynamically update the Ajax.ActionLink with values coming back from the controller.  Here, I have moved it into the PartialView (arguabley you could move the entire table including the fetch more link into the PartialView and have it be even cleaner).

Comment: If this were without ajax and I always return `View` there would be no problem. But you pass a `ViewModel`, where you count the `skip`, to a `PartialView`, not `View`. Whereas the `View` has it's own `ViewModel` where the `skip` always equals 10. How can I get the 'skip' from a `PartialView` in the `View`?

Comment: Put your Ajax.ActionLink inside of the Partial view for _StudentDetailsList.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to split the table like that. When the `View` is loaded for the first time it is ok, but then I will be having one `<table>` tag and multiple `</table>` tags with multiple `Load More` links.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the way. You should replace the Ajax.ActionLink for a link with $.get, and retrieve the skip by counting the numbers of rows at the tbody that you already have:

First replace the ActionLink for:

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">Load More Students here!</a>
```

Second, create this function to do the get:

```
$('mylink').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Gets the number of rows that you alredy have loaded
    var rowCount = $('studentTable').find('tbody > tr').length;
    //The URL for the get, with the number of rows
    var url = "http://www.myurl.com/controller/action?skip=" + rowCount;

    $.get(url, function (data) {
       //Append the content from the partial view to the tbody
       $('studentTable').find('tbody').append(data);
    });
});
```

I think that this is a good way as well!

Hopes this help you!